# Transmitting serial data over Wi-Fi

Tags: rs232

I have a device that outputs a TX RX RS232 serial string. Is there a way I can take this locally to an Arduino and send over Wi-Fi to another Arduino?

I'm relatively new to all of this so any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Serial-to-WiFi Tutorial using ESP8266](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.14/tutorials/Programming/serialwifi.html)

Comment: you need a RS232 to TTL Serial converter to connect a RS232 device to Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and there are many tutorials how to do it.
Most popular one uses ESP8266 module. What is even more interesting you can use ESP module as an Arduino (and yes, you can program it using Arduino IDE).